# How to delete slashes using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

in the following code how to delete `\` slashes using PHP and HTML

`<input alt#\"\" src=\"/ckfinder/userfiles/files/DSC_0017.JPG\" style=\"width: 400px; height: 266px\" type=\"image\" /></p>`

is this possible and if yes how?

Thanks in advance for your valuable support

Comment: look up `stripslashes()` or `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)